# Can the Collector Edition Dyes be transferred between users?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a bit fussy about my character's appearance, and always want to look my best when slaying hordes of demons.

I [read](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66491/8462) that there are two collector-edition dyes I do not have (Beige and Dark Grey), which have unlimited uses.

Is it possible to purchase/trade these dyes from another player?

Or am I stuck with finding someone who has these dyes, and getting them to dye my gear for me if I want these colors? (If you have CE dyes, it might be an interesting source of income for you if you can get people to trust you enough to give them their items) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trade the CE dyes to other players; they are account bound.

Comment: Nothing stops me from getting someone else to dye my clothes with those colors through, right? Might be an interesting source of income for those with CE dyes if they can get people to trust them enough to give them their items.... :)

Comment: @Rachel Interesting thought! I'd recommend updating the body of the question with that!

Comment: Yeah, the items do not appear to become account bound after dying them - money making opportunities abound!

Comment: (I'll confirm that when I get home - that's from memory).  This seems like a worrisome avenue for scammers, though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Sure, I'll add that thought to the question although I'm not sure if it adds any value :) I also asked another question to find out if [equipment could get dyed in the trade window](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67349/8462), and apparently you can't so you'll need to be trustworthy to sell your services as a cloth dyer :)