# Can equipment be dyed in a trade window?

Tags: diablo-iii

Collector Edition dyes are account bound and cannot be traded, however can they be used in a trade window to dye someone else's gear?

I do not have the CE dyes, but can see myself potentially wanting to dye my gear with those colors, and was wondering if I could pay someone to dye my gear without giving them my gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Diablo does not support acting on items in the trade window in the way that games like World of Warcraft do.  You'll need to find someone you trust to apply the CE dyes from their own inventory and then give the item back to you.