# Aesthetic Items in Diablo 3 (Limited Edition)

Tags: diablo-iii

I just read about this for the Limited Edition:

**Diablo III - Aesthetic Artifacts**

Call forth glowing angel wings, unfurl an exclusive banner sigil, and dye your armor sets with the Bottled Cloud or Bottled Smoke items.

Does that mean that if we have a Normal account, we are unable to obtain Bottled Cloud/Bottled Smoke dye items? Even via cash from the Auction House in the future?

I understand if the Angel Wings are locked to the account itself (and the banner), but the dye should be considered as a misc item, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Collector Edition Dyes be transferred between users?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67337/can-the-collector-edition-dyes-be-transferred-between-users)

Comment: i'm saying via cash on the auction house as well. i thought it was a misc item (meaning they could buy it for a few gold, but its actually just a bottle that can be reused again and again)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot obtain the dye without the Collectors Edition since they are account-bound. However, you can ask someone with the Collectors Edition to dye your items for you.

Of course, you will need to find someone with the dye that you can trust with your items.

Answer (score 2):

As per my friend who is a collector's edition user:

"All items that came with the collector's edition are account bound."

Of course meaning they cannot be sold or transferred. However, I have given him items and had him dye them for me then give them back.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that if we have a Normal account, we are unable to
>   obtain Bottled Cloud/Bottled Smoke dye items? Even via cash from the
>   Auction House in the future?

Correct

> I understand if the Angel Wings are locked to the account itself (and
>   the banner), but the dye should be considered as a misc item, right?

also locked to account, as mentioned, others can dye items for you.